# How do i add a audio file field to my database table?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to set up a local database in Visual Studio 2013 and i currently have a table with an "id" and a "name" field that works but i can't find anything in the dropdown menu under "Data Type" that has to do with audio files.

How do i add this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think in those cases you should save it just as bytes array

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `binary/varbinary`:

- Use `binary` when the sizes of the column data entries are consistent.
- Use `varbinary(n)` when the sizes of the column data entries vary
  considerably.
- Use `varbinary(max)` when the column data entries exceed
  8,000 bytes.

Further information at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188362(v=sql.120).aspx).